# A proof of the Weyl Character formula via fixed point formula and

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

I've been looking all day for a reference or notes that prove the Weyl character formula via a fixed point formula and the Borel-Weil-Bott theorem. Does anyone know of these off hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two accounts of this.

A Lefschetz Fixed Point Formula for Elliptic Complexes: II. Applications
M. F. Atiyah and R. Bott
Annals of Mathematics , Second Series, Vol. 88, No. 3 (Nov., 1968), pp. 451-491 
([JSTORE link](http://www.jstor.org/sici?sici=0003-486X%28196811%292:88:3%3C451%3aALFPFF%3E2.0.CO;2-B&))

This account is complete but not as clear as Bott's "On induced representations" (proper citation below). It is in Volume 4 of his collected papers but I cannot find it online.

Bott, Raoul. "On induced representations." Collected Papers 48 (1994): 402.